# XCode 11 : Embedded Binaries Framework Inside Framework Project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks, xcode11

I made a new framework project that contain other frameworks. In older version of XCode, I can put the other framework in "Embedded Binaries" section in General so whenever it archived it wouldn't show any framework inside the framework file (Umbrella Framework), and whenever I used it in My App, it worked.

In my case, I already updated to XCode 11 and there is no "Embedded Binaries" section in General. If I set the third party framework to "Do Not Embed" and tried it in My App, it crashed because the My App can't find the third party framework.

Is there any best practise for me to make the third party hide inside my framework project ?

Answer (score 0):

I already looked for the answer and found this article

[Adding a third party framework inside a first party framework in Xcode](https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/adding-a-third-party-framework-inside-a-first-party-framework-in-xcode-3ba58cfd08da)

So, it said I need to add path of my third party Framework in Build Setting -> Runpath Search Paths & Frameworks Search Paths.

And then I set my third party Framework in General to Do Not Embed, after that I tried to Archive/Run the project and get the Product/Framework and put it in the App.

It worked.